# How to show that the Wiener measure is singular with respect to a normal law

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-analysis, wiener-measure

We have a Gaussian process $X$, $X_t:=B_t - tB_1$, where $B$ is a $BM$, $t\in[0,1]$.
Let $\nu$ be the law of $X$ and $\mu$ the Wiener measure.

How can I show that $\mu$ is singular with respect to $\nu$?

I know that $X_t$ is distributed $N(0, t^2-t)$ but I don't know if this helps in any way. I presume I have to find a set so that $\nu$ on it is 0 and $\mu$ not, but I do not know how to continue.

Comment: Consider the event $A=$"To equal $0$ at time $1$". Then $\mu(A)=0$ while $\nu(A)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\nu(\{\omega:X_1(\omega)=0\})=1$ but $\mu(\{\omega:B_1(\omega)=0\})=0$.

Comment: Thank you! May I just ask if it is enough to say that this is because $μ({ω:B_1(ω)=0})=P({ω:B_1(ω)=0})=0$? Or do I misunderstand the Wiener measure?

Comment: @Ravonrip The Wiener measure is the law of $B$.